# Missing outlets in XCode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.2, xcode4.5, outlet

I'm doing my first iOS app and it should look like the following screenshot:

[image]

Nevertheless, I seem to have missing some connections, such as the ´window´and the ´delegate´ as the ´File's owner´, according to the screenshot of my project in Xcode:

[image]

I'm following the book iOS programming - the big nerd ranch guide, and since this books is using an older version of XCode -4.2 I think- I guess my problem has to do with this.

Could anyone please help me find out how to create those missing connections?
How can I add that `window` to `Window` in the `Outlets` section and the `delegate` to the `File's Owner` in the `Referencing Outlets` section?
Do I really need to add them?

Thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT: This is my header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface QuizAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    int currentQuestionIndex;
    // The model objects
    NSMutableArray *questions;
    NSMutableArray *answers;

    // The view objects
    IBOutlet UILabel *questionField;
    IBOutlet UILabel *answerField;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

- (IBAction)showQuestion:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)showAnswer:(id)sender;

@end
```

Comment: There are differnces in xcodes versions and how to manage. Drag  from referencing outlet to the object..it will create that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each view controller has a .h and .m files what I can see in your header file is that you are adding IBOutlet(s) to the App Delegate which is wrong. Please add them to the corresponding View Controller.

Then open the storyboard or the xib file and attached the outlets to the UI elements.

Comment: What is "wrong" about having outlets in the app delegate?

Comment: outlets are used to connect UI elements to the controller, AppDeleagate on the other hand recieve app events like start, suspend, open url. Outlet maybe linked to UI element that is not activate at that time

Answer (score 0):

Make a control click and hold on the circle and drag to the element to which you want to create the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not have "IBOutlets" specified correctly in your header. Or you may not have the class of your object specified correctly in IB or the header.

Comment: I added the header file to my question, but I have the IBOutlets already added there